# Update data SelectInput in shiny modules

Tags: r, shiny, module, selectinput

I am facing an issue in updating the data selected using SelectInput and modules in Shiny. In a few words, when I select the data to be loaded into the selectInput panel, it updates it on the first selection, but if I then want to go from dataset 1 to dataset 2, the data does not update.
Below you cand find the code to reproduce the specific problem.

```
# Libraries

pacman::p_load(shiny, shinydashboard,
              tidyverse, data.table, DT, stringr,
              ggplot2, plotly,
              survival, survminer, GGally, scales,
              shinycssloaders)

version <- 0.1

# GENERAL PARAMETERS

box.height <<- 700
select.box.height <<- 150
selectAB.box.height <<- 250
select.box.width <<- 12

# Data

men1_1.norm <<- as.numeric(rnorm(50))
men1_1.pois <<- as.numeric(rpois(50, lambda = 1))
men1_2.norm <<- as.numeric(rnorm(50, mean = 1))
men1_2.pois <<- as.numeric(rpois(50, lambda = 2))

# ui modules

LoadDataUI <- function(id, 
                      label = "Select the data:", 
                      sel = "Data 1", 
                      choic = c('Data 1','Data 2')){
 ns <- NS(id)
 selectInput(ns("data.sel"),
             label = label,
             choices = choic,
             selected = sel)
}

PlotUI <- function(id){
 ns <- NS(id)
 plotOutput(ns("plot"))
}

# ui

ui <- dashboardPage(
 dashboardHeader(title = paste('My Dashboard',version,sep='')),
 dashboardSidebar(
   sidebarMenu(
     id = "sbMenu",
     #Tabs for different data displays
     menuItem("1st Menu", tabName = "men1", icon = icon('microscope'))
   )
 ),
 dashboardBody(
   tabItems(
     tabItem(tabName = 'men1',
             h2(strong('tab 1')),
             fluidRow(
               ### !!!! TO REMOVE ERROR MESSAGES !!!!
               # tags$style(type="text/css",
               #            ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
               #            ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
               #,
               box(title='Select data to load:', height= select.box.height, width = select.box.width,
                   LoadDataUI("data1")
               ),
               box(title='Normal', height=box.height,
                   PlotUI("hist_norm1")
               ),
               box(title='Poisson', height=box.height,
                   PlotUI("hist_pois1")
               )
             )
         
     )
   )
 )
)


# server modules

Panel <- function(id){
 moduleServer(
   id,
   function(input, output, session) {
     return(
       list(
         data = reactive({input$data.sel})
       )
     )
   }
 )
}

LoadDataServer <- function(id, menu, data_selected
){
 moduleServer(
   id,
   function(input, output, session){
     dt <- reactive(data_selected)
     data <- reactiveValues(norm = NULL,
                            pois = NULL)
     data$norm <- reactive({get(paste0(menu(),"_", dt(), ".norm"), envir = .GlobalEnv)})
     data$pois <- reactive({get(paste0(menu(),"_", dt(), ".pois"), envir = .GlobalEnv)})
     return(
       data
     )
   }
 )
}


PlotServer <- function(id,data = NULL){
 moduleServer(
   id,
   function(input, output, session) {
     x <- reactive(as.numeric(data))
     output$plot <- renderPlot({
       hist(x(), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
     })
     # output$plot <- renderPlot({
     #   if(is.null(data)){return(NULL)}else{
     #       hist(data, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')}
     # })
   }
 )
}


# server

server <- function(input, output, session){
 data1 <- Panel("data1")
 observeEvent(data1$data(), {
   updateSelectInput(session, 'data.sel', selected = input$data.sel)
 })
 pnl1 <- reactive(
   switch(data1$data(),
          "Data 1" = "1",
          "Data 2" = "2")
 )
 d1 <- LoadDataServer("data1", menu = reactive({input$sbMenu}), data_selected = pnl1())

 # Plot

 # menu1
 output$plot <- PlotServer("hist_norm1", data = d1$norm())
 output$plot <- PlotServer("hist_pois1", data = d1$pois())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
version <- 0.1

# GENERAL PARAMETERS

box.height <<- 500
select.box.height <<- 150
selectAB.box.height <<- 250
select.box.width <<- 12

# Data

men1_1.norm <<- as.numeric(rnorm(50))
men1_1.pois <<- as.numeric(rpois(50, lambda = 1))
men1_2.norm <<- as.numeric(rnorm(150, mean = 1))
men1_2.pois <<- as.numeric(rpois(150, lambda = 2))
# ui modules

LoadDataUI <- function(id, 
                       label = "Select the data:", 
                       sel = "Data 1", 
                       choic = c('Data 1','Data 2')){
  ns <- NS(id)
  selectInput(ns("data.sel"),
              label = label,
              choices = choic,
              selected = sel)
}

PlotUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    plotOutput(ns("plot"))
  )
  
  
}

# ui

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = paste('My Dashboard',version,sep='')),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "sbMenu",
      #Tabs for different data displays
      menuItem("1st Menu", tabName = "men1", icon = icon('microscope'))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = 'men1',
              h2(strong('tab 1')),
              fluidRow(
                ### !!!! TO REMOVE ERROR MESSAGES !!!!
                # tags$style(type="text/css",
                #            ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                #            ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
                #,
                box(title='Select data to load:', height= select.box.height, width = select.box.width,
                    LoadDataUI("data1")
                ),
                box(title='Normal', height=box.height,
                    PlotUI("hist_norm1")
                ),
                box(title='Poisson', height=box.height,
                    PlotUI("hist_pois1")
                )
              )
              
      )
    )
  )
)


# server modules

Panel <- function(id){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      return(
        list(
          data = reactive({input$data.sel})
        )
      )
    }
  )
}

LoadDataServer <- function(id, menu, data_selected
){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session){
      dt <- reactive(
        switch(data_selected(),
               "Data 1" = "1",
               "Data 2" = "2")
      )
      observe({print(dt())})
      data <- reactiveValues(norm = NULL,
                             pois = NULL)
      data$norm <- reactive({get(paste0(menu(),"_", dt(), ".norm"), envir = .GlobalEnv)})
      data$pois <- reactive({get(paste0(menu(),"_", dt(), ".pois"), envir = .GlobalEnv)})
      return(
        data
      )
    }
  )
}


PlotServer <- function(id,data){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      #x <- reactive(as.numeric(data))
      
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        x <- as.numeric(data())
        hist(x, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
      })
      # output$plot <- renderPlot({
      #   if(is.null(data)){return(NULL)}else{
      #       hist(data, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')}
      # })
    }
  )
}


# server

server <- function(input, output, session){
  data1 <- Panel("data1")
  # observeEvent(data1$data(), {
  #   updateSelectInput(session, 'data.sel', selected = input$data.sel)
  # })
  
  # pnl1 <- reactive(
  #   switch(data1$data(),
  #          "Data 1" = "1",
  #          "Data 2" = "2")
  # )
  d1 <- LoadDataServer("data1", menu = reactive({input$sbMenu}), data_selected = data1$data )
  
  # Plot
  
  # menu1
  PlotServer("hist_norm1", data = reactive(d1$norm()) )
  PlotServer("hist_pois1", data = reactive(d1$pois()) )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because the data you pass to the `PlotServer` is not reactive. I've made the additional changes:

- stored the data in the beginning in a list to avoid using `get`; it's easier and safer to directly work with a data object
- removed the `data_selected` argument from the `LoadDataServer` as this information is determined by the `input$data.sel` variable, however this is only accessible from within the module and not the the main app `server`. For the initialisation, you need this information only in the UI part of the module (which you already have implemented). This allows me to remove `observeEvent` code in your main app `server` as this is handled by the module.

```
# Libraries

# pacman::p_load(shiny, shinydashboard,
#                tidyverse, data.table, DT, stringr,
#                ggplot2, plotly,
#                survival, survminer, GGally, scales,
#                shinycssloaders)

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

version <- 0.1

# GENERAL PARAMETERS

box.height <<- 700
select.box.height <<- 150
selectAB.box.height <<- 250
select.box.width <<- 12

# Data

data_object <- list(
  men1_1 = list(
    norm = as.numeric(rnorm(50)),
    pois = as.numeric(rpois(50, lambda = 1))
  ),
  men1_2 = list(
    norm = as.numeric(rnorm(50, mean = 1)),
    pois = as.numeric(rpois(50, lambda = 2))
  )
)

# ui modules

LoadDataUI <- function(id, 
                       label = "Select the data:", 
                       sel = "Data 1", 
                       choic = c('Data 1' = "1",'Data 2'  = "2")){
  ns <- NS(id)
  selectInput(ns("data.sel"),
              label = label,
              choices = choic,
              selected = sel)
}

PlotUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  plotOutput(ns("plot"))
}

# ui

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = paste('My Dashboard',version,sep='')),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "sbMenu",
      #Tabs for different data displays
      menuItem("1st Menu", tabName = "men1", icon = icon('microscope'))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = 'men1',
              h2(strong('tab 1')),
              fluidRow(
                ### !!!! TO REMOVE ERROR MESSAGES !!!!
                # tags$style(type="text/css",
                #            ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                #            ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
                #,
                box(title='Select data to load:', height= select.box.height, width = select.box.width,
                    LoadDataUI("data1")
                ),
                box(title='Normal', height=box.height,
                    PlotUI("hist_norm1")
                ),
                box(title='Poisson', height=box.height,
                    PlotUI("hist_pois1")
                )
              )
              
      )
    )
  )
)


# server modules

Panel <- function(id){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      return(
        list(
          data = reactive({input$data.sel})
        )
      )
    }
  )
}

LoadDataServer <- function(id, menu
){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session){
      
      data <- reactiveValues(norm = NULL,
                             pois = NULL)
      observeEvent(input$data.sel, {
        data$norm <- data_object[[paste0(menu(), "_", input$data.sel)]][["norm"]]
        data$pois <- data_object[[paste0(menu(), "_", input$data.sel)]][["pois"]]
      }) 
      
      return(
        data
      )
    }
  )
}


PlotServer <- function(id,data = NULL){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        hist(data(), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
      })
    }
  )
}


# server

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  d1 <- LoadDataServer("data1", menu = reactive({input$sbMenu}))
  
  # Plot
  
  # menu1
  output$plot <- PlotServer("hist_norm1", data = reactive({d1$norm}))
  output$plot <- PlotServer("hist_pois1", data = reactive({d1$pois}))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you pass the complete `d1` object to the `PlotServer`, you could remove the `reactive({})` you currently need to pass the `norm` or `pois` data.

I recommend to read into how to pass data between modules and module capsulation, you can start with [mastering shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-modules.html) or [my introduction to modules](https://github.com/jonas-hag/structure_your_app).